# JAVA OCA Oracle Certified Associate Java SE 8 Programmer I Exam_1Z0-808

Tags: java, oracle

Which of the following are true? (Choose all that apply)

A. Encapsulation uses package private instance variables.

B. Encapsulation uses private instance variables.

C. Encapsulation allows setters.

D. Immutability uses package private instance variables.

E. Immutability uses private instance variables.

F. Immutability allows setters

Correct answers is B,C,E.
The question is, what does "private instance variable package" refer to?
I understand that a package cannot have an access modifier applied, is it?
Thank you very much for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means default access modifier for instance variables or methods which can be acccessed from the other classes in same package.

Default: It is accessible in the same package from any of the class of package.

To access you can create an object of the class. But you can not access this variable outside of the package.
Also, how you make it default, it's by not specifying any access modifiers. Example:

```
public class Student{
   String name;
   void displayName(){
     System.out.println(this.name);
   }

}
```